# Mysql Query: switch if record come from table news or news_collect

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
    UNION
(SELECT * FROM news_collect WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
```

Now in the while loop I need to switch if record come from table news or news_collect...How do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem adding an custom field, keeping the column count the same.

```
(SELECT *, 'news' as source FROM news WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
    UNION
(SELECT *, 'news_collect' as source FROM news_collect WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
```

Then you can use `switch($aRow['source'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query as follows:

```
(SELECT news.*, 'news' coming_from FROM news WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
    UNION
(SELECT news_collect.*, 'new_collect' FROM news_collect WHERE Del='0' ORDER BY `Date` DESC)
```

(assuming "coming_from" is not a column of the "news" table)

Then use column "coming_from" to distinguish between the record's origin.